# I don't know how to use angular material controls in my application

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have installed angular material

[image]

I have created Material Module

[image]

I have imported this module in app module

[image]

But in any template in which I insert a control I always get the same error of "is not a known element:"

For example, here I need a date picker

[image]

Any idea, please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid creating a dedicated material module for tree shaking.

But the issue is probably that you only imported the modules, and did not export them.

Try adding an `exports` array to your material module.